# Pandas Dataframe with text and problems with encoding some characters

Tags: python, regex, pandas, character-encoding, decoding

I have a dataset that includes a column with some text (song lyrics).

sometimes in the text there are words ( or symbols) not correcly decoded, here an exemple:

```
'I keep trying Ainâ\\x80\\x99t no denyingWe should be together nowI canâ\\x80\\x99t imagineYouâ\\x80\\x99re with another man Baby'
```

in this case, searching the original lyrics, those "codes" (â\x80\x99) indicates the single quote - apostrophe - but I have lots of rows and I cannot check every one of them, and also I have text from languages like russian, chinese, greek and so on...

I thought to use regex and find all those substring but I don't know if the pattern is the same (a letter, two backslash , x plus two numbers)

or there is simply some encoding argument that "read" all the characters?

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your question right, you need to find the right encoding of your file.

**Find the file encoding like this:**

```
# import the chardet library
import chardet 

# use the detect method to find the encoding
# 'rb' means read in the file as binary
with open(your_file, 'rb') as file:
    print(chardet.detect(file.read()))
```

This snipet will print the right encoding of the file like below:

```
{'encoding': 'UTF-16', 'confidence': 1.0, 'language': ''}
```

Now open your file with the right encoding.

If you dont have chardet library installed:

```
pip install chardet
```

Hope this will help you.